# String to date time conversion Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a source table which has dates stored in string format as below:

```
1984-10-28 00:00:00
1988-11-22 00:00:00 
1990-01-08 00:00:00
1983-06-22 00:00:00
```

Then created a table test1 as below:

```
mk -t xyz.test birthdate:timestamp
```

When I write a query to convert all the dates from source table to timestamp and save it to test1 it gives an error:

```
SELECT FORMAT_UTC_USEC(birthdate) AS birthdate FROM [sourcetable] LIMIT 10

Error: Invalid schema update. Field birthdate has changed type
Job ID: [Project]:job_5P4gFVl4wiYuyXL0vY5VZNtCZOU
```

Please help if I am doing anything wrong

Answer (score 12):

Never mind. I found it. I was overlooking a big part of bigquery's query reference document.

TIMESTAMP()
Convert a date string to a TIMESTAMP data type.

SELECT TIMESTAMP("2012-10-01 01:02:03");

Returns: 2012-10-01 01:02:03 UTC

So the correct query as below:
SELECT TIMESTAMP(birthdate) AS birthdate FROM [sourcetable] LIMIT 10

Comment: Are you running into problems with birthdate given that TIMESTAMP only goes back to the year 1970? Wouldn't you want to use DATETIME instead (which goes back to year 1000)?

Answer (score 0):

You're running a query that updates a table in place? Are you using WRITE_TRUNCATE? If not, you'll just end up appending to the table with a different schema.

Comment: WRITE_TRUNCATE is same as "Owerwrite table", right? If I do that then it overwrites the table schema as well. Basically I want to convert date string to timestamp and store it to Destination table as timestamp

Comment: you could do `SELECT *, FORMAT_UTC_USEC(birthdate) as birthdate_str FROM [sourcetable]

Comment: I tried it earlier but it still saves "birthdate_str" field as "STRING" type in destination table. I wanted "birthdate_str" field in destination table as "TIMESTAMP" so I can run the quries against it